# In jdbc, where do you specify host credentials?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

According to [this link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html), to connect to a mysql db you use the following string:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sakila?profileSQL=true
```

Instead of localhost, I have a remote linux vm that hosts my mysql database.  Where would the credentials to log into that vm be?

Comment: jdbc:mysql://address=(protocol=tcp)(host=localhost)(port=3306)(user=test)/db

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getConnection(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace your localhost with the machine name of your remote linux. You don't need to login into the remote vm as you will be connecting directly to the exposed 3306 port.  Just fill out the credentials of your DB user in the connection string, that should be sufficient.

Comment: thanks, i didnt need the jdbc string, i had that; I was unaware that you didn't need the credentials of the host machine mysql was on.

Answer (score 0):

try this

jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?user=root&password=root